# It is possible to make a pull up menu in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I´m starting to develop a application with Xamarin.forms we have the mockups and we need to implement somethink like a pull up menu / accordion menu. This component have to show over the content of the main page. I found a sketch from someone who wants to make the same as I, but no one give him a solution
[image]

This is the mockup of the component that I want to implement

[image]

[image]

I´ve searched a lot but i can not find something similar to the component that I want. Can some one please tell me if is possible to have components like this in xamarin? maybe using a external library

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  But it's not a standard UI element on either iOS or Android, so you would need to write it yourself of find a third party library

Comment: Thank you for answer Jason :) Did you know with what library can I achieve this? I´ve tried with Syncfusion but the "accordion menu" doesn´t  to be the one component that i need

Comment: No idea.  Asking for tool recommendations is explicitly off-topic on SO

Comment: Do you mean [this discussion](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/362), probably [this package](https://github.com/galadril/Xam.Plugin.SimpleBottomDrawer) is worth trying.

Comment: Hope this will help you [BottomSheet in Xamarin Forms](https://medium.com/xamarinlife/bottomsheet-in-xamarin-forms-f99fd8b48bc4)